# Mockito Junit Not able to mock Call

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, java-11

I am trying to test a method in Junit Mockito, but I am not able to mock the method for a Repo call (List projectBasicDetailsList =
projectBasicDetailsRepository.findByEvProjectMaster(evProjectMaster);) . It is instantiating a blank object which is not expected, the test should create a mock List of ProjectBasicDetails , Instead it is creating a null array.
Even the log is pointing of unused mock.

Code :

```
@Test
  public void testCreateServiceRequest() {
    String evProjectId = String.valueOf(RandomGenerator.randomLong());
    System.out.println("evProjectId is " + evProjectId);
    EvProjectMaster evProjectMaster = new EvProjectMaster();
    evProjectMaster.setEvProjectId(Long.valueOf(evProjectId));
    System.out.println("evProjectMaster is " + evProjectMaster.getEvProjectId());
    ProjectBasicDetails projectBasicDetails = new ProjectBasicDetails();
    List<ProjectBasicDetails> projectBasicDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();

    
    projectBasicDetails.setEvProjectMaster(evProjectMaster);
    System.out.println(
        "projectBasicDetails is " + projectBasicDetails.getEvProjectMaster().getEvProjectId());
    projectBasicDetailsList.add(projectBasicDetails);
    System.out.println("pbd list is : " + projectBasicDetailsList.size());

   when(projectBasicDetailsRepository.findByEvProjectMaster(evProjectMaster))
        .thenReturn(projectBasicDetailsList);

    evProjectMaster.setProjectStartDate(RandomGenerator.randomDate().toLocalDate());
    evProjectMaster.setProjectEndDate(RandomGenerator.randomDate().toLocalDate());
    when(evProjectMasterRepository.findByEvProjectId(Long.valueOf(evProjectId)))
        .thenReturn(evProjectMaster);
    EquipmentEventDetails equipmentEventDetails =
        EquipmentEventDetailsGenerator.randomEquipmentEventDetails();
    equipmentEventDetails.setPlanEventStartDate(RandomGenerator.randomDate().toLocalDate());
    List<EquipmentEventDetails> equipmentEventDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    equipmentEventDetailsList.add(equipmentEventDetails);
    when(equipmentEventDetailsRepository.findByEvProjectSourceId(evProjectId))
        .thenReturn(equipmentEventDetailsList);
    when(ofsEventsManager.checkSingleEvent(equipmentEventDetailsList)).thenReturn(true);
    EquipmentDetail equipmentDetail = equipmentEventDetails.getEquipmentDetail();
    when(equipmentDetailRepository
        .findByEquipmentSysId(equipmentEventDetails.getEquipmentDetail().getEquipmentSysId()))
            .thenReturn(equipmentDetail);
    ServiceRequestModel srm = new ServiceRequestModel();
    ServiceResponseModel serviceResponse = new ServiceResponseModel();
    serviceResponse.setReturnStatus("S");
    serviceResponse.setServiceRequestNo(RandomGenerator.randomString());

    try {
      when(charlieClient.triggerSrCreationInCharlie(srm)).thenReturn(serviceResponse);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<ServiceResponseModel> serviceResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
    serviceResponseList.add(serviceResponse);

    assertEquals(
        charlieEvIntgManager.createServiceRequest(evProjectId).get(0).getServiceRequestNo(),
        serviceResponse.getServiceRequestNo());
  }


}
```

---

Method to test:

```
@Override
  @Transactional
  public List<ServiceResponseModel> createServiceRequest(String evProjectId) {
    log.info("evProjectId is " + evProjectId);
    boolean singleEvent = false;
    String incidentRespondDate = null;
    String eqpSysId = null;
    EvProjectMaster evProjectMaster = new EvProjectMaster();
    evProjectMaster.setEvProjectId(Long.valueOf(evProjectId));
    List<ProjectBasicDetails> projectBasicDetailsList =
        projectBasicDetailsRepository.findByEvProjectMaster(evProjectMaster);
    evProjectMaster = evProjectMasterRepository.findByEvProjectId(Long.valueOf(evProjectId));
    List<EquipmentEventDetails> equipmentEventDetailsList =
        equipmentEventDetailsRepository.findByEvProjectSourceId(evProjectId);

    singleEvent = ofsEventsManager.checkSingleEvent(equipmentEventDetailsList);
    log.info("value of single event: {}", singleEvent);
    log.info(" projectBasicDetails size " + projectBasicDetailsList.size());
```

---

The log which I am getting on running the unit test is :

```
evProjectId is 935603632
evProjectMaster is 935603632
projectBasicDetails is 935603632
pbd list is : 1
18:12:05.787 [main] INFO com.ge.seawolf.events.charlie.manager.impl.CharlieEvIntgManager - evProjectId is 935603632
18:12:05.801 [main] INFO com.ge.seawolf.events.charlie.manager.impl.CharlieEvIntgManager - value of single event: true
18:12:05.804 [main] INFO com.ge.seawolf.events.charlie.manager.impl.CharlieEvIntgManager -  projectBasicDetails size 0
[MockitoHint] CharlieEvIntgManagerTest.testCreateServiceRequest (see javadoc for MockitoHint):
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at com.ge.seawolf.events.charlie.manager.impl.CharlieEvIntgManagerTest.testCreateServiceRequest(CharlieEvIntgManagerTest.java:755)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at com.ge.seawolf.events.charlie.manager.impl.CharlieEvIntgManager.createServiceRequest(CharlieEvIntgManager.java:666)
```

---

What am I doing wrong here. Any clue will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you overridden the equals method in EvProjectMaster.class?

```
when(projectBasicDetailsRepository.findByEvProjectMaster(evProjectMaster)).thenReturn(projectBasicDetailsList);
```

Try to change evProjectMaster to Mockito.any() in upper code, does it works?

Comment: It worked with any()...can u explain why the actual object is not working..but any() is able to mock the call

Comment: Mockito doesn't match your object with the method call object. Maybe your EvProjectMaster.class haven't overridden the equals method or more properly check with what parameters your mock method call.
From Mockito documentation:
`Arguments passed are compared using <code>equals()</code> method. Read about {@link ArgumentCaptor} or {@link ArgumentMatcher} to find out other ways of matching / asserting arguments passed.`